# How to create token for list using JWT in Angular

Tags: angular, jwt, token

In my Spring Boot application I have tables `Ticket` and `User` and I want to show list of `tickets` which was ordered by `User`.

I create User authentication using JWT and I want to create token with list of `tickets`.

I created tokens for login, name, email etc, like you see on the pictures. Everything works OK. But also I need to create token for list of tickets. For this `tickets: Ticket[];`

jwt-responce.ts

```
export class JwtResponse {
accessToken: string;
type: string;
username: string;
user_id: number;
name: string;
surname: string;
email: string;
authorities: string[];
tickets: Ticket[];
}
export class Ticket {
ticket_id: number;
place: number;
user_id: number;
flight_id: number;
}
```

token-storage.service.ts

Here I have problem with methods `saveTickets` and `getTickets`. I don't know how to create this methods correctly for `tickets: Ticket[];`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Ticket} from '../ticket';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'AuthToken';
const USERNAME_KEY = 'AuthUsername';
const NAME_KEY = 'AuthName';
const SURNAME_KEY = 'AuthSurname';
const USERID_KEY = 'AuthUserId';
const EMAIL_KEY = 'AuthEmail';
const TICKET_KEY = 'AuthTicket';
const AUTHORITIES_KEY = 'AuthAuthorities';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {
private roles: Array<string> = [];
private tickets: Array<Ticket> = [];

constructor() {
}

signOut() {
window.sessionStorage.clear();
}

public saveToken(token: string) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
}

public getToken(): string {
return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
}

public saveUsername(username: string) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USERNAME_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(USERNAME_KEY, username);
}

public getUsername(): string {
return sessionStorage.getItem(USERNAME_KEY);
}

public saveName(name: string) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(NAME_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(NAME_KEY, name);
}

public getName(): string {
return sessionStorage.getItem(NAME_KEY);
}

public saveSurname(name: string) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(SURNAME_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(SURNAME_KEY, name);
}

public getSurname(): string {
return sessionStorage.getItem(SURNAME_KEY);
}

public saveEmail(email: string) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(EMAIL_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(EMAIL_KEY, email);
}

public getEmail(): string {
return sessionStorage.getItem(EMAIL_KEY);
}

public saveAuthorities(authorities: string[]) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY, JSON.stringify(authorities));
}

public getAuthorities(): string[] {
this.roles = [];

if (sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)) {
  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY)).forEach(authority => {
    this.roles.push(authority.authority);
  });
}

return this.roles;
}

getUser_id(): number {
return Number(sessionStorage.getItem(USERID_KEY));
}

saveUser_id(user_id: number) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USERID_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(USERID_KEY, String(user_id));
}

/*getTickets(): Ticket[] {
this.tickets = [];
if (sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)) {
  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(TICKET_KEY)).forEach(tickets => {
    this.tickets.push(tickets.tickets);
  });
  return this.tickets;
  }
  }

saveTickets(tickets: Ticket[]) {
window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TICKET_KEY);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(TICKET_KEY, JSON.stringify(tickets));
}*/
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../auth/token-storage.service';
import { AuthLoginInfo } from '../auth/login-info';

@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
form: any = {};
isLoggedIn = false;
isLoginFailed = false;
errorMessage = '';
roles: string[] = [];
/*  tickets  = new Array(1);*/
 private loginInfo: AuthLoginInfo;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private tokenStorage:    TokenStorageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
if (this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
  this.isLoggedIn = true;
  this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getAuthorities();
  this.tickets = this.tokenStorage.getTickets();
}
}

onSubmit() {
console.log(this.form);

this.loginInfo = new AuthLoginInfo(
  this.form.username,
  this.form.password);

this.authService.attemptAuth(this.loginInfo).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
    this.tokenStorage.saveUsername(data.username);
    this.tokenStorage.saveName(data.name);
    this.tokenStorage.saveSurname(data.surname);
    this.tokenStorage.saveEmail(data.email);
    this.tokenStorage.saveTickets(data.tickets);
    this.tokenStorage.saveAuthorities(data.authorities);
    this.tokenStorage.saveUser_id(data.user_id);

    this.isLoginFailed = false;
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
  /*  this.tickets = this.tokenStorage.getTickets();*/
    this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getAuthorities();
    this.reloadPage();
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
    this.isLoginFailed = true;
  }
);
}

reloadPage() {
window.location.reload();
}
}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TokenStorageService } from '../auth/token-storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
info: any;

constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.info = {
  token: this.token.getToken(),
  username: this.token.getUsername(),
  name: this.token.getName(),
  surname: this.token.getSurname(),
  email: this.token.getEmail(),
  tickets: this.token.getTickets(),
  authorities: this.token.getAuthorities(),
 };
 }

logout() {
this.token.signOut();
window.location.reload();
}
}
```

Here is my html class to show the data like on the picture:

```
<div *ngIf="info.token; else loggedOut">
<h5 class="text-primary">Twoje dane</h5>
<p>
<strong>Login:</strong> {{info.username}}<br/>
<strong>Name:</strong> {{info.name}}<br />
<strong>Surname:</strong> {{info.surname}}<br />
<strong>Email:</strong> {{info.email}}<br />
<strong>Role:</strong> {{info.authorities}}<br />
<strong>
<label>List of tickets: </label>
<div *ngFor="let tickets of info.tickets">
  <label>Place: </label> {{ tickets.place }}
</div>
</strong>
```

[image]

Comment: Two things. 1. You don't say what problems you have with this - you mention that you don't know how to do this, but you seem to have the methods done, just commented out. Did you try this way? What did end up in your storage?

2. Your logout method only deletes them locally. Might be a good idea to hit a logout endpoint on auth server, to delete the auth token there too.

Comment: I commented out that methods because it's wrong, with that methods informations about user (like on the picture) doesn't shown at all, only the blank page.

Comment: You also seem to have a disconnect between what is in your html template and the login class. Are they the same thing? Where do you load/setup this `info` object on your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `saveTickets` example (commented out one) seems a bit overengineered. Why not just store and restore in the same way:

```
saveTickets(tickets: Ticket[]) {
  sessionStorage.removeItem(TICKET_KEY);      
  sessionStorage.setItem(TICKET_KEY, JSON.stringify(tickets));
}

getTickets(tickets: Ticket[]) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(TICKET_KEY));
  } catch (e) {
    // no or invalid data. Just return empty.
    return [];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, `info` object is here `home.component.ts`, I've added this class to my question. I tried your methods, now I don't get an empty page, but `list of tickets` is still empty.

Comment: Happy to help :) And collect some more Angular tag answers, a few more for my Angular tag badge :)